# ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods Are Inconsistent

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, error-handling, pagemethods

Given the following javascript code:

```
    function ValidateFlagAsUrgent() {
        selectedValuesList = document.getElementById('<%= _searchResultsUserControlUserControl.SelectedValuesHiddenFieldClientID %>').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location.href + '/' + 'AreAnyOfTheSelectedTasksInMyProjects',
            data: '{"selectedTasks":"' + selectedValuesList + '"}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: AjaxProjectManagerSucceeded,
            error: AjaxFailed,
            async: false
        });
    }

    function AjaxProjectManagerSucceeded(result) {
        if (result.d == true) {
            document.getElementById('<%= _variableWarningCioLabel.ClientID %>').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('<%= _areAnyOfTheSelectedTasksInMyProjects.ClientID %>').value = 'true';
        }
        else {              
            document.getElementById('<%= _areAnyOfTheSelectedTasksInMyProjects.ClientID %>').value = 'false';
        }
    }

    function AjaxFailed(result) {   
  alert('Error: ' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
```

and given the following Page Method in my code behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool AreAnyOfTheSelectedTasksInMyProjects(string selectedTasks)
    {
        using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Guid> selectedTasksThatAreInMyProjects =
                from st in selectedTasks.Split('|')
                join t in context.Tasks
                    on st equals t.Number.ToString()
                join pr in context.ProjectRepresentatives.Where(pr => pr.UserID == ContextHelper.CurrentUserID)
                    on t.Request.ProjectID equals pr.ProjectID
                select t.ID;

            return selectedTasksThatAreInMyProjects.Any();
        }
    }
```

The JQuery AJAX method invocation ***occasionally*** returns 'Error: 200 OK'.

The infrequent nature of the errors leads me to believe that my web server "gets in a bad state", and (for whatever reason) is unable to service the incoming requests.

As I understand it, 'Error: 200 OK' *may* mean that the returned content is malformed and does not conform to the specified contentType. While that's all well and good, I need to understand why my code may be periodically susceptible to this condition.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Methods are *not* inconsistent.

But a query string can vary 'window.location.href'.

This page will always reference the same code-behind file, so there's no reason to lean on 'window.location.href'. I can hard code the page name instead.